Generic way to use as_ref / as_mut
I've got two very similar functions in rust: get_node and get_node_mut is it possible to avoid the duplicate code without macros ?
pub(crate) struct Node<Key, Item: GetKey<Key>> {
    pub left: Option<Box<Node<Key, Item>>>,
    pub right: Option<Box<Node<Key, Item>>>,
    pub items: Option<Vec<Item>>,
    pub can_split: bool,

    _marker: PhantomData<Key>,
}

pub struct Bucket<Key, Item: GetKey<Key>, const K: usize> {
    pub(crate) root: Box<Node<Key, Item>>,
    pub(crate) key: Key,
}

impl<...> Bucket<...> {
    fn get_node(&self, key: &Key) -> (&Node<Key, Item>, usize) {
        let mut bit_index = 0;
        let mut node = self.root.as_ref();

        // Navigate to the first bucket node
        while node.items.is_none() {
            node = match key.has_bit_at(bit_index) {
                false => node.left.as_ref().unwrap(),
                true => node.right.as_ref().unwrap(),
            };

            bit_index += 1;
        }

        (node, bit_index)
    }

    fn get_node_mut(&mut self, key: &Key) -> (&mut Node<Key, Item>, usize) {
        let mut bit_index = 0;
        let mut node = self.root.as_mut();

        // Navigate to the first bucket node
        while node.items.is_none() {
            node = match key.has_bit_at(bit_index) {
                false => node.left.as_mut().unwrap(),
                true => node.right.as_mut().unwrap(),
            };

            bit_index += 1;
        }

        (node, bit_index)
    }
}

can we use something that hnadles both as_mut / or as_ref depending of the expected return type ?

Does this answer your question? How to avoid writing duplicate accessor functions for mutable and immutable references in Rust?, Is there a safe way to reuse the same code for immutable and mutable variants of a function?, How to implement a trait for any mutability?

Here's a generic version. Note that it is long. There's two main drawbacks: you lose a lot of implicit conversions, so this needs to use an explicit as_deref instead of as_ref. And you can't reborrow unless you use references to references, which is why items takes &self, aka &&Node.

It's worth observing that this is a common frustration with Rust, and something that the keyword generics initiative is (amongst other things)  hoping to address.

@drewtato It's a case of the cure being worse than the disease, but I applaud the tour de force!

I would like to mention (promote) that I'm working on a crate to solve this. It's already working, but it's not yet production-ready. See the crate and my post about it.

@FZs It would be nice for the crate to have an examples/ directory that shows how to solve cases like this one.

@user4815162342 Yes, that's a good idea. I'll create one when I get to it. Although there are a few things that probably need to happen before that can, like reviews of the unsafe foundations and making the std plugin (that makes it ergonomic to use std types with generic mutability). I'll start collecting examples though...
